# Using jQuery width() to change Google Chart table column widths doesn't actually change width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I've written a function to align the columns of multiple Google Chart tables. jQuery is used to actually change the column widths but I'm getting some strange behaviour. I've given a listing of the function below.

```
match_table_column_sizes: function(table_wrapper, match_table_wrapper) {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(match_table_wrapper, 'ready', function() {
        var table_chart = table_wrapper.getChart();
        var match_table_chart = match_table_wrapper.getChart();

        var resize_function = function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < match_table_wrapper.getDataTable().getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
                var match_cell = $('#' + match_table_wrapper.getContainerId() + ' td.google-visualization-table-th')[i];
                var cell = $('#' + table_wrapper.getContainerId() + ' td.google-visualization-table-th')[i];
                match_cell_width = $(match_cell).outerWidth();

                // ---- This is the weird bit --- //
                $(cell).width(match_cell_width);
                console.log(match_cell_width);
                console.log($(cell).width());
            }
        };
        resize_function();

        google.visualization.events.addListener(match_table_chart, 'sort', resize_function);
    });
},
```

The strange behaviour is that, the output to the console is never match_cell_width. It doesn't change! I've even tried setting it to just something like '100px' and it doesn't update at all.

I've also tried the following with similiar results.

```
$(cell).css('width', match_cell_width + 'px');
$(cell).css('width', '100px');
```

If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated because I am completely stumped.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Try logging the variables such as cell in console. i don't think your selectors are working from the look of it. a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) might help.

Comment: I thought the same as well, but it's definitely giving the right element! :(